# Make middle body box grow to bottom of footer

Tags: html, css

Using this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/A3vZV/), how would it be changed so the red border grows to the top of the footer.  The end result would be the red box takes up the middle part of the page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="body">BODY</div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header { height: 60px; background-color: #999; }
.footer { height: 61px; background-color: #999; }
.body { border: 1px solid red; }

/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
* { margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; height: auto !important; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto -60px auto; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */ }
.footer, .push { height: 60px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */ clear: both; }
form { height: 100%; }
/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
```

**Answer update**
I accepted @dfsq's answer below, and drew inspiration from it to create the final solution http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/A3vZV/6/

Comment: Should the footer move beyond the visible window or should the footer always stay fixed at the end of the visible page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy task. I was struggling with this layout recently and found next approach working. There is cool trick with applying huge `padding` and opposite `margin` to your `.body` container and at the same time giving `overflow: hidden` to the `.wrapper`:

```
.body {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 0 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
.wrapper {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3vZV/2/

Comment: Very close.  However, I don't see the margin at the bottom.  Ultimately I want to use a margin:5px and padding:5px where the border is visible.  But it seems the border extends way beyond the footer.  Is this the case, or can you change the fiddle to move the bottom border up a bit?

Comment: You can adjust margin easily and padding http://jsfiddle.net/A3vZV/4/
But you can't move the border up. Sorry. I spent a lot of time fighting with this layout and was not able to find any better solution. However you can use `footer:before` to emulate this border, maybe this will work for you.

Comment: @John This solution does extend the body past the footer. It's the same solution that I usually see when I've tried to fix this problem in the past. Good luck.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Buy the way, I'm also curious, do you know better solution? I was not able to come up with anything else.

Comment: @dfsq Nope. My solution so far is to not use the sticky footer if I need more control. Although I'd think it wouldn't be too hard to do in javascript.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Yep, agree.. well I know another one: you can use flex box model to make proper sticky footer, but it doesn't have good browser support yet.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this one ...

```
.body { position : absolute; top : 60px; bottom : 60px; 
        width : 100%; 
        border: 1px solid green;
        overflow : hidden; }
```

Cheers!

**Edit #1**: for correct clipping add `overflow`

**Edit #2**: slightly better is `left : 0px; right : 0px;`instead of `width : 100%;`

Comment: If it was that easy.. check how it works with long content: http://jsfiddle.net/A3vZV/3/

Comment: @ *dfsq*: thanks for notifying though this was not part of the question ;-) not a big deal ...